# symfony2 unable to send email via gmail

Tags: php, gmail, swiftmailer, symfony-2.2

I have been trying to send email using swiftmailer, however I am not able to do so, I am getting following exception

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Swift_TransportException: "Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "myusername@gmail.com" using 1 possible authenticators" at /home/ubuntu/Symfony/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/Esmtp/AuthHandler.php line 184 [] []
```

Can anybody tell what am I missing here? It looks like authentication is failing for some reason.

here is the snippet from my config file:

```
swiftmailer:    

  transport:  gmail
  encryption: ssl
  auth_mode:  login
  host:       smtp.gmail.com
  username:   myusername@gmail.com
  password:   password
```

My Dev server has ubuntu v13 OS

Comment: I am having a similar issue. The problem may lie with gmail account configuration.

Comment: @mika Do we add or give some sort of permission in gmail ? are you sure about configuration in gmail?

Comment: I was actually able to resolve this changing configuration in https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps while logged in my gmail account. it may or may not be what blocks you. Still worth giving it a try?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing from your config_dev.php

```
encryption: ssl
auth_mode:  login
```

There is no need to specify the encryption: and  auth_mode:  if you're using transport: gmail 
See the symfony2.3 cookbook   [How to use Gmail to send Emails](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/gmail.html)

Quick and dirty way to  test the email options.
Init a **new** symfony 2.3 project and in the Default controller in acme /DemoBundle  put this action.

```
/**
 * @Route("/mail")
 * @Template()
 */
public function mailAction() {


    $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Hello Email')
            ->setFrom('send@example.com')
            ->setTo('mymail@example.com')
            ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                    'DemoBundle:Default:email.txt.twig', array('name' => 'User1')
            )
            )
    ;
    $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

    return array('name' => 'whatever');
}
```

Twig templates in Acme/Demo/Bundle/Resources/views/Default
Frontend template

mail.html.twig

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
  {% block body %}
     This is mail template 
  {% endblock %}
```

The mailer template.
email.txt.twig

```
This is a test email to {{name }}
```

Going to the /mail should send the email.

Comment: Nope, I tried above change I am still getting the error, also I have visited the page how to use email to send emails several times, still unable to make it work